# Is it possible to get the exit code of ant scp task?

Tags: ant, scp

I'm using ant scp task in a loop and i have turned off failonerror. But i need to track the failed iterations. Is there anything like resultproperty for exec? I can use exec instead of scp on unix, but i need to do on windows.

Any help would be appreciated...

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could put the [recorder task around scp invocations](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/recorder.html) and evaluate the logfile later.

Example is from the doc:

```
<whatever >
    <record name="log.txt" action="start"/>
    <scp ...
    <record name="log.txt" action="stop"/>
<whatever />
```